# Validation android keystore file (php)

Tags: php, android, mobile, mobile-application, android-keystore

I'm developing a service where the user can build and sign android applications. 
Users use their own signatures (*.keystore). 
I am developing this service using php.

For signing applications, the user uploads signatures with alias, keypass and storepass. 
I need a validator for checking signatures. 
I guess that I can use keytool for this purposes, send the file on server and try to do something with it. 
But maybe somebody knows how can I check *.keystore file without using keytool, e.g: how can I check some parts of file manually via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in three steps:

1. Install last version of jdk on server, it contains keytool utility
2. Use php exec function for manipulating with the signatures by using the keytool
3. Parse answer from ketool on php side